# clear the data of type object

Tags: java, object

I using type object and I fill it with data inside loop and at the end I want to clear the data inside ,I don't see any option to clear it (with .+CTRL SPACE) and I don't want to create new instance for it because I want to create object type just once ,is there a workaround to clear it?

I want to do the following just once for specObject, i.e. create instance type list or object and than I have loop that I fill the data inside this object ,when i finish and want to create new instance in specObject I want to clear it before ,how should I do that?

```
List<Object> itemObject = null;
        Object specObject = null;

        // Check instance type whether is list or specific object instance
        if (multiplicity.equals(MULTI_N)) {
            itemObject = new ArrayList<Object>();
            return itemObject;
        } else if (multiplicity.equals(MULTI_1)) {
            return specObject;
        } else {
            return specObject;
        }
```

Comment: Some code here would be extremely handy.

Comment: We have no idea what type you're talking about, either. You haven't really explained why you don't want to create a new instance, either - you've basically said, "I don't want to because I don't want to" rather than giving a real reason.

Comment: @JonSkeet-added my code

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean, or the context in which this code runs. Is it in a method?

Comment: So, this method returns either an empty `List<Object>` or an `Object` that is `null`? That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `clear` method on the `List` object. That will remove all elements without the need to create a new instance. The documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear%28%29).

**Just to note on object references**

> when i finish and want to create new instance in specObject I want to clear it before ,how should I do that?

Let's say you have a list:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you add some string objects to this list:

```
strings.add("Hello");
strings.add("There");
strings.add("StackOverflow");
```

Then you nullify the `strings` object.

```
strings = null;
```

You have effectively removed all of the elements inside the list? Why? Well when you declare `ArrayList<String> strings;`, you're not creating a new object. You're creating a new reference (pointer) to an object. To illustrate this:

```
String s = "Hello";
String s2 = s; // s2 points to the same object that s points to.
String s3 = "Another String"; // S3 points to a different object.
```

The one exception to this rule is if you declare:

```
String s = "Hello";
String s2 = "Hello"; // s2 will point to the same object as s.
```

When an object isn't pointed to by anything, it is removed by the Garbage Collector. So effectively, if you declare:

```
strings = null;
```

You're removing all of the `String` child objects that you added to.